# How do I redirect an email in Outlook with the redirecting email ID as the sender

Tags: microsoft-outlook, redirection

I need to redirect an email either in Outlook or in Gmail which is received from `123@abc.com` to `xyz@456.com` from my email ID without exposing `123@abc.com` to the reviewer (`xyz@456.com`)

Is there a way to redirect mails like that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My hunch is this would have to be done within the email server; AFAIK, the email header can always be seen if the email's raw code is reviewed

Comment: How is your issue going? Does the method work for you? If your issue has been resolved, you could mark the helpful reply as best answer or share your method, your action will be helpful to others who encounter the same issue:)

Answer (score 0):

Messages that are redirected will appear to come from the original sender. You cannot change original sender address in outlook side.

Could you create a new mail account which can expose to the reviewer? If you do it, you could configure 2 redirect rules to achieve your goal.

- The first rule is to redirect mails from 123@abc.com to
  newaccount@abc.com
- The second rule is to redirect mails from newaccount@abc.com to
  xyz@456.com

Hope these help to you.